# How to change toolbar buttons color?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I can change tintcolor every button by

```
 UIToolbar* tb = [[self navigationController] toolbar];
 for (UIBarButtonItem * item in tb.items)
        item.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

But can not change tintcolor all buttons by `[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]] ;`
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with the [`UIAppearance` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Somewhere in your app (I do this in the app delegate) put something glide this...

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:1]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

**EDIT**

Just saw that you're using `UIToolBar` not Tab Bar. So you can do this...

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolBar class] set.....
```

You can mess around with other properties too like...

```
// this uses an embedded font to set the font of tab items.
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont bariolRegularFontOfSize:14]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can do the same sort of thing with labels, buttons, navigation bars, etc...